# How to merge two arrays together, concatenating the corresponding elements?

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

I'm not asking about the easy merging of array like `c = a+b` (which would yield `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

What I am looking for is to join the contents of two arrays, so that the end-result would be as the following (given `a` and `b` written previously).

```
c = what-do-I-write-here? # [14,25,36]
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Introduction

You can [*`zip`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) together your two lists, forming a new lists that will contain *two-element tuples* (pairs), where each pair consists of the elements at the corresponding index, from the two lists.

```
Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 20 2015, 11:28:25)
[GCC 5.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> list (zip (a,b))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

This in turn will make it very easy to iterate over each pair, and create a new list with the desired contents.

---

#### Sample Implementation

In your question you have written that the result should be `[14,25,36]` — implying that you are looking to concatenate the elements lexiographically, but then have the result still be *ints*.

You could solve it in a easy manner using code such as;

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = [ int(''.join (map (str, xs))) for xs in zip (a,b) ]
```

```
c is now [14, 25, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to match the appropriate elements, and from there it's just a matter of converting them to strings and joining them:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [''.join(str(s) for s in x) for x in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li = [int(str(t[0]) + str(t[1])) for t in list(zip(a,b)) ]

print(li)

[14, 25, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another possibility:

```
[int(x) for x in map(operator.concat, str(a), str(b)) if x.isdigit()]
```

the int-casing can also be done afterwards:

```
map(int,[x for x in map(operator.concat, str(a), str(b)) if x.isdigit()])
```